# Dynamic form target is redirecting to new window instead of loading in iframe

Tags: html, typescript, iframe

I have an HTML with Typescript. The target and Iframe name is set dynamically.

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/blah" [target]="toIFrame">
   <input ......./>
   <input ......./>
</form>
<iframe [name]="toIFrame" [id]="toIFrame">
</iframe>
```

the value of toIFrame is set in ngAfterViewInit. Tried setting the value in OnInit but still the data is loaded in new window instead of iframe.

Comment: Why are the html attributes wrapped in square brackets?

Comment: You may have to use javascript to listen for a click event on the link then replace iframe. Target can be same window, new window, parent frame or top frame.

Comment: Square brackets signifies the binding of the variable to attribute.